# One datagrid per row of ItemsSource binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Currently have a single datagrid defined in my XAML file that binds (itemsource) a collection of data (called view) and this is displays in one big table (as expected and working perfectly).

However what I need now is to create a datagrid PER row, thus ending up with many datagrids all containing a single row of data.

The only thing I can think of is:
- dynamically create the datagrids in-code (somehow) and remove it from the XAML
- populate the itemsource of each of these dynamically created datagrids with a specific row of the data, for example (pseudo-code):

> > for each row of view
> >     create new datagrid
> >     assign row as the itemsource binding

Does anyone have any better suggestions? Can this even be done the way I am proposing it? Is there a better/simpler way?

The reason - customer wants to PRINT each row on a seperate PAGE so I will create many datagrids and pass each one to printvisual independantly to achieve this.

CODE:

```
// this is the datasource, essentially we want to show one recipe per printed page (so per datagrid)
List<ViewRecipe> View
```

XAML:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding View}"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False"
          Height="Auto"
          CanUserAddRows="False"
          CanUserDeleteRows="False"
          CanUserResizeColumns="False"
          CanUserResizeRows="False"
          CanUserReorderColumns="False"
          IsReadOnly="True"
          GridLinesVisibility="None">
  <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
      <Setter Property="FontWeight"
              Value="Bold" />
      <Setter Property="FontSize"
              Value="12" />
    </Style>
  </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
  <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Type"
                        Width="200"
                        FontSize="12"
                        Binding="{Binding Path=Name}" />
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Ingredients"
                            Width="*">
      <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                    CanUserAddRows="False"
                    CanUserDeleteRows="False"
                    CanUserResizeColumns="False"
                    CanUserResizeRows="False"
                    CanUserReorderColumns="False"
                    IsReadOnly="True"
                    GridLinesVisibility="None"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Ingredients}">
            <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
              <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                <Setter Property="FontWeight"
                        Value="Bold" />
                <Setter Property="FontSize"
                        Value="12" />
              </Style>
            </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
            <DataGrid.Columns>
              <DataGridTextColumn Header="Ingredients"
                                  Width="*"
                                  FontSize="12"
                                  Binding="{Binding Path=IngredientName}" />
              <DataGridTextColumn Header="Quantite"
                                  Width="*"
                                  FontSize="12"
                                  Binding="{Binding Path=Qty}" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
          </DataGrid>
        </DataTemplate>
      </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
  </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: I don't care much about how the end results look on the screen. The reason for all this is that customer wants to PRINT each row on a seperate PAGE so I will create many datagrids and pass each one to printvisual independantly to achieve this (with PrintVisual and a for-loop print each "datagrid")

Comment: @JSchwartz post the relevant code and XAML. Otherwise It's all speculations.

Comment: @debracey nice idea about the ASP repeater control. Except it's completely irrelevant IN WPF. I wish I could downvote comments.

Comment: @HighCore posted source code and XAML. Does this help?

Comment: @JSchwartz , your XAML lacks all `<` . Could you repost it?

Comment: Oups ... fixed XAML... how is the solution itself dependant on the datagrid in question? Really curious to see what your idea is

Answer (score 1):

You can form a list of list of `ViewRecipe` and then pass it as `Itemssource` to `ItemsControl`, which `ItemsTemplate` is you `DataGrid`.

code:

```
List<List<ViewRecipe>> ViewExtended = new List<List<ViewRecipe>>();

foreach (var r in View)
{
    var l = new List<ViewRecipe>();
    ViewExtended.Add(l);
}
```

XAML

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ViewExtended}">
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}">

    ......

    </DataGrid>
    </DataTemplate
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: This doesn't compile: Error 7 foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid' because 'System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

Comment: @JSchwartz, I gave you an idea how to split data to multiple datagrids (btw working idea, i checked it in code). And there is no, in my example, `foreach` loops over `DataGrid`